# Rosbridge server release for ROS 1

Tags: ros, rosbridge-server, rosbridge-suite

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently detected that there was a bug in the rosbridge server package when closing sockets.

Library Version: ros1

ROS Version: noetic

Platform / OS: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

I saw that they fixed the bug  (https://github.com/RobotWebTools/rosbridge_suite/issues/721) and merged (https://github.com/RobotWebTools/rosbridge_suite/pull/722)

The current release candidate for the ros-noetic-rosbridge-server package is  *0.11.13-1focal.20220107.015434*

Is there any chance that these changes will be reflected in a new release?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/398977/rosbridge-server-release-for-ros-1/) by [ribes](https://answers.ros.org/users/101894/ribes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2022-04-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After asking the developers, I was notified that a new version(0.11.14) of the rosbridge server package for [melodic](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/pull/33560) and [noetic](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/pull/33559) is on its way.

---

Originally posted by [ribes](https://answers.ros.org/users/101894/ribes/) with karma: 11 on 2022-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1